# Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'rails_user'@'localhost' (using password:YES)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

I am trying to create a database and connect it with my rails app.

When I try to check if my database are properly connected via:

```
rails db:schema:dump
```

It gives me the ff error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'rails_user'@'localhost' (using password:
YES)
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:dump
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

This blows my mind as did used the exact password when I created the DB:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: rails_user
  password: grace0512
  host: localhost

development:
  <<: *default
  database: test_project_development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: test_project_test
```

I did try this:

```
grant all on simple_cms_development.* to 'rails_user'@'localhost' identified by '<password>';
flush privileges;
```

But did not solve my issue. Any help please?

I really need to solve this to move forward!

Comment: I know it's a long shot, but make sure there's no space after `password: grace0512 ` .. to be sure, wrap all your values in `""` . `password: "grace0512"`

Comment: Did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you fixed it yet?

I changed it slightly and put

```
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON demo_project_development.* to rails_user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Although I still received Rails warnings, it successfully did a schema dump afterwards!

Answer (score 0):

The SQL command you need to run is:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test_project_development.* to 'railsuser'@'localhost' 
IDENTIFIED BY 'grace0512';
```

Please also run this command immediately after to be consistent:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test_project_test.* to 'railsuser'@'localhost' 
IDENTIFIED BY 'grace0512';
```

There is no need to use flush privileges as MySql automatically reloads the grant tables.

If that did not work, did you run **bundle install** on command line in your project root after you updated database.yml? if so, recheck if you mispelled the username or password.